# Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException when comparing two strings of two different string arrays

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, arrays, compareto

I'm coding trough codingbat.com/java and ran into an error i don't understand. I got two String arrays and want to compare them. If I just use the arrays all works fine (but the result is not right). To get the right result I programmed a helper function which eliminates all duplicates of an array. I tested the helper function, it returns the array shortened of the duplicates.

I can retrieve the values in the new Arrays with `_a[i]` etc., and don't get errors, but if i use `_a[0].equals(_b[0]) or _a[0].compareTo(_b[0])` I get a `NullPointerException (_a[0] == _b[0] works fine...)`.

If I just use the original arrays a,b the code runs without problems. I don't comprehend why i get a NullpointerException there.

Thanks for any help!

Code:

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {

      String[] _a = killDuplicate(a);
      String[] _b = killDuplicate(b);

      int ai=0, bi=0,count=0;

      for (int i = 0; ai < _a.length & bi < _b.length; i++){
         if ( _a[ai].compareTo(_b[bi]) > 0) { //NullPointerException here, but not if I use a,b
            bi++;
         } else if ( _a[ai].compareTo(_b[bi]) < 0){  //NullPointerException here, but not if I use a,b
            ai++;
         } else { 
            count++;
            ai++;
            bi++;
         }  
      }
      return count;
}
```

**Helper Function:**

```
 public String[] killDuplicate(String[] a){

     String temp = "";
     int counter = 0, counter2 = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if (! a[i].equals(temp)){
           temp = a[i];
        } else {
           a[i] = "";
           counter++;
        }
     }

     String[] result = new String[a.length - counter];

     for (int i = 0; counter2 < counter; i++){
        if (a[i].equals("")) {
           counter2++;
        }
     } else {
        result[i-counter2] = a[i];
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: The item returned by `_a[ai]` or `_b[bi]` is null, hence your error.

Comment: k, my helper function seems to be wrong, I just had a bad testcase for it which returned a right value, but it doesn't for other values. I try to fix it. Edit: Yeah a bug in the helper function, see answer below, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you assume that your array of strings is sorted, otherwise your `killDuplicate` method wouldn't make sense at all.

The problem with your code is that in the second `for` loop in `killDuplicate` method you iterate with condition `counter2 < counter` which says iterate until all found duplicates are passed. So when you find your last duplicate you exit without filling the rest of the array. Try with example: `new String[]{"A", "A", "B", "C"}` you'll get `[A, null, null]`.

There are numerous things that can be improved but the simplest modification of your code below. (I've changed only the second `for` loop)
    public String[] killDuplicate(String[] a) {

```
    String temp = "";
    int counter = 0, counter2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (!a[i].equals(temp))
            temp = a[i];
        else {
            a[i] = "";
            counter++;
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[a.length - counter];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].equals("")) continue;
        result[counter2] = a[i];
        counter2++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, i forgot to mention that the arrays are sorted at this exercise. And the rest is also right, thanks :)